# Create a DLL and LIB file using command line from Visual Studio C++ 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, linker, static-libraries

I have tried to use the following option from LIbrarian > Command Line

```
/OUT:"mylib.lib" "mylib.dll" /DEF:"mydef.def"
```

However, it only generated the static library. When my DLL filename precedes the `/OUT` directive, it only produces DLL, but not LIB.

I simply want to create DLL and LIB files for my library without having to use `__declspec(dllimport)` or `__declspec(dllexport)`

Could someone help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
/OUT:"mylib.dll" /IMPLIB:"mylib.lib" /DEF:"mydef.def" /DLL
```

From the command line, you need `/DLL` but the `/IMPLIB` is not strictly necessary because the default name will depend on your DLL name.

When compiled from the IDE, the compile has a `/LD` parameter, which ensures that `/DLL` is passed on to the linker. So if you're building the command line yourself you need to make it explicit.

Comment: sorry! It still didn't generate the LIB, only DLL. THe output is :

`1>LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/IMPLIB:dynlibToSl.lib'; ignored
1>LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/DLL'; ignored
1>     Creating library dynlibToSl.dll and object dynlibToSl.exp
1>  dynlibToSl.vcxproj -> C:\vcpp\dynlibToSl\Debug\dynlibToSl.lib`

Comment: @hagubear are you running `CL`, `MSBUILD`, `LINK` or something else?

Comment: I just noticed your comment about the /LD parameter. If I am adding it as a command line option from the property sheet of my Visual Studio Project, do I need to add /LD followed by what you have provided in your answer?

Comment: I think I can see where my misunderstanding is. I assumed you're linking from the command line by running LINK, but you are trying to edit the command line in VS2010, right? If so, you don't need to do that - if necessary, create a new project, using the Win32 option and DLL target, and just make sure to add your .DEF file to the project too. Everything should then compile and link with no changes.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing things up.  The "Librarian > Command Line" settings are only used when you build a static library project.  The output filename extension should be .lib, the /DEF option does not apply.  The .lib output file itself is *not* an executable file, static libraries are just simple bags of .obj files.  They need to be used later in another project that builds an EXE or DLL to be useful.

A DLL is a completely different animal, it is an executable file format and the /DEF option is useful to name the exported functions.  When the linker builds the .dll then it will *also* create a .lib file for the DLL.  Which is not a static library, it is the *import library* for the DLL.  A small file that just contains the names of the exported functions, it has no resemblance to a static library.  Which you can then use when you build another project that uses that DLL.

Not sure how you got in this pickle, I assume you just started with the wrong project template.  File + New Project, Visual C++, Win32, Win32 Project.  OK, Next, select the "DLL" radio button for the Application Type setting.  Your project is now properly configured to generate the DLL and LIB.  Use the Linker, Input, Module Definition File setting to specify your DEF file.

Comment: I know what you are saying. I am simply trying to not use those microsoft template function to delcare the import export stuff for DLLs. When you build DLL, you should be able to build it with either visual studio or code blocks or eclipse. The idea is to have a DEF file so that the DLL generation and function import export is easier. However, if I cannot generate a DLL and a static library at the same time, I am happy to accept that. It seems like I cannot do it actually! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: __declspec(dllexport) isn't exclusive to Microsoft compilers, GCC and Clang accept it as well and treat it the same way.  Maybe you are trying too hard to avoid a useful feature.  Using /DEF is however specific to the Microsoft linker.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to build both a DLL and a static link library from the same source, you could just create two projects within a solution - a DLL project and a static library project - and point them at the same source files.  Rebuild solution, presto!, DLL and static library. `:^)`